# How can a non angular class use an angular service and its deps

Tags: javascript, angular, es6-modules

I am trying to link 3 files Angular Component, Plain JS Class and Angular Service:

My angular component (AppComponent) should initialise my plain js class (CommonCode)... However, my plain js class needs to call and angular service.

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Service:

```
import { AnotherAngularService } from '/core/service2';
import { AnotherAnotherAngularService } from '/core/service3';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class Foo2Service {

    this.serviceOneCache = null;

    // Service code
    constructor(public anotherAngularService:AnotherAngularService, public anotherAnotherAngularService:AnotherAnotherAngularService) {

        this.anotherAngularService.getCache().subscribe(response) {

                this.serviceOneCache = response;

            }
            .error();        
    }

    init() {
      // Code that returns something
      return 'test';
    }

    getFooCache() {
        return this.http.get...... etc etc
    }
}
```

JS Class

```
import { FooService } from '/core/fooservice';

export class CommonCode  {
    this.fooCache = null;

    // Service code
    constructor(public fooService: FooService) {

        this.fooService.getFooCache().subscribe(response) {

                this.fooCache = response;

            }
            .error();        
    }

    func1() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Common Code is not a plain js class, it is a TypeScrip class. What speaks against making CommonCode a service?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm the problem is to do with services and singletons. When Component instantiates JSClass it needs to have its own 'this', and not shared. As on a single page, other Angular components should also be able to instate their own JSClass.

Comment: You can provide the service on component level. ```@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  providers: [ CommonCode ],
})``` As a result each Component will have it's own instance of `CommonCode` service

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm wasnt aware of this.. Will try find some material on it and how to use CommonCode from providers. Do you want to add an answer so i can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, you could convert `CommonCode` TS class to an Angular Service and provide it on Component Level.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  providers: [ CommonCode ],
})
export class AppComponent  {

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```